# Regular Expressions and languages of alphabets with substring

Tags: regular-language

Right now I'm learning for a test in cs and I have my problems with regular expressions. Here is example of a question I don’t understand.

We have a given alphabet Σ = {0, 1} and L1. L1 represent any word with odd number of 0(zeros) and exactly twice 1 (ones).

The prof. showed us an example how the solution should look like: 
**Σ = {a, b} with L1**.

L1 represents any Word in which the sub-words **aa** or **bb** occurs.

**L1 = (a ∪ b)*  (aa ∪ bb)*  (a ∪ b)***

thank you for your help

Comment: is it exactly twice 1 mean two ones in the string L1={011,101,110,00011,...}?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```regex
(?mx)
^
(?=0*10*10*$) # check if the word consists of only 0s and exactly two 1s
(?:..){1,}.   # check if the word length is odd
$
```

Demo on [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/gPz4fc/7). There you can find an exhaustive explanation of this regular expression.